# How can I write this correctly?

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to write a script that allows me to refer to a text file with a list of directory names and move only those target directories elsewhere. I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t var < list_of_directory_names
for i in `expr ($var)`
do
cp -r ${old_directory[$i]} new_directory/
done
```

but I get the following error message:

```
syntax error near unexpected token: '($var)'
```

The reason why I am using `expr` is I initially used `{[$var]}` but it gives me the error

```
value too great for base
```

as most of my directory names start with "0" and the program see this as octal notation which sh cannot recognize.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t var < list_of_directory_names
for i in "${var[@]}"; do
    cp -r "$i" ./new_directory/
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it still gives me the value too great for base error.

Comment: Don't use `expr ($var)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the array for something else, don't bother creating it. Use a `while` loop instead.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  cp -r "$i" ./new_directory/
done < list_of_directory_names
```